# Circular programming - replace list elements by minimum value

Tags: haskell

I've just read [this article](https://wiki.haskell.org/Circular_programming) about `circular programming`. It seems so alien to me. Although I can imagine the feedback as lazily evaluated thunk that will be evaluated to desired result later, just can't wrap my head around it. So I decided to write function that replaces every element of a list with it's minimum value.

```
trace :: (a -> c -> (b,c)) -> a -> b
trace f a = b
    where (b,c) = f a c

repminList :: (Num a, Ord a) => [a] -> [a]
repminList = trace repIIminList 

repIIminList [x] m = ([m], x)
repIIminList (a:as) m = let (replaced, m) = repIIminList as m 
                        in (m : replaced, min a m)
```

But `repminList [1,2,3]` equals to `[2,3,3]`. What would be the correct version?

Comment: Who is down voting this question? Please state your reason. I want to know.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your problem is that you have two different `m` variables and one shadows over the other so you don't end up using the actual circular variable at all. Here's the fixed version of your `repIIminList`:

```
repIIminList [x] m = ([m], x)
repIIminList (a:as) m = let (replaced, m') = repIIminList as m
                        in (m : replaced, min a m')
```

Here `m` is the final, smallest element of the list that you receive as circular parameter. The `m'` returned from the recursive call to `repIIminList` is the smallest value seen so far, so it's important that you append the *final* smallest value (i.e. `m`) to the result list and then update the current smallest value by returning `min a m'`.

Answer (score 4):

That's a pretty cool technique! Here's a working program that's inspired by yours (I didn't really read the article except to glance at the picture, so this may not be exactly what the author intended, but it works):

```
looper :: (inputT -> feedfwdT -> feedbackT -> (feedbackT, outputT)) -> inputT -> feedfwdT -> outputT
looper f input primer = output
  where (feedback, output) = f input primer feedback

min_feedback :: (Ord a) => [a] -> Maybe a -> a -> (a, [a])
min_feedback [] (Just p) _ = (p, [])
min_feedback (x:xs) partial_min minimum = (feedback, minimum:output)
  where new_partial_min = case partial_min
                of Nothing -> Just x
                   Just p -> Just $ min x p
    (feedback, output) = min_feedback xs new_partial_min minimum

min_looped :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [a]
min_looped input = looper min_feedback input Nothing

main = print $ min_looped [1,4,6,2,6,3,-1,6,3,6,10]
```

The key here is that you need more than the feedback channel, you also need a feedforward channel to determine the minimum value on the first pass through the loop. My ASCII art skills are not up to the standard set in the article, so you'll just have to make do with this paint drawing:
[image: Circular programming example]
The feedforward is the minimum value seen so far in the list. The primer kickstarts the feedforward channel. The feedback channel takes the result value from the feedforward channel back up to the start of the list. Finally the feedback value becomes the minimum value that gets used to fill the output list.

Comment: is it impossible without feedforward?

Comment: Yes. However, shang's answer is actually better than mine, and is probably closer to what the author of the article intended. His `m` variable is the feedforward and his `m'` variable is the feedback. The improvement is that he used the feedback channel to fill in the output list directly, rather than bringing it all the way back to the front and passing it along down the list one more time (the brown "minimum" arrow in my diagram).

Answer (score 4):

It's

```
repIIminList (x:[]) m' = ([m'], x)
repIIminList (x:xs) m' = (m' : xs', min x m) where (xs', m) = repIIminList xs m'
```

`m` is a current minimum, `m'` is a final minimum, `xs` is a current list, `xs'` is a final list. That is, `repIIminList` receives a list and a number and recursively replaces every element in a list with this number. `repIIminList` also computes the minimum of the list. `trace` applies `repIIminList` to the minimum, computed by `repIIminList` itself.

Using the state monad you can rewrite this in a pretty explicit way:

```
repminList :: [Int] -> [Int]
repminList  []    = []
repminList (x:xs) = evalState (go xs) x where
    go  []    = get >>= return . (:[])
    go (x:xs) = modify (min x) >> flip (:) <$> go xs <*> get
```

Or using CPS style directly:

```
repminList :: [Int] -> [Int]
repminList  []    = []
repminList (x:xs) = foldr (\x r -> (\(x:xs) -> x:x:xs) . r . min x) (:[]) xs x
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm too tired to analyze your code, divine your intent and the bug.  However, I'll happily show you how I avoid having to think that hard when doing basic knot tying.

Its this State Monad, yay!  My use of the State monad (below) is just a little plumbing that keeps track of a single current value in a manner that allows the value to be looked-up and updated.

- `repMin` kicks off the computation by taking into account the empty list then running the state monad.
- Our worker action `f` is provided with the input list and the minimum element in the list (currently a thunk, do not evaluate!)
- `f` traverses the list computing the minimum on the way and replacing each element with the soon-to-be-known-but-not-yet-evaluatable minimum value `m`.

The code:

```
import Control.Monad.State

repMin :: [Int] -> [Int]
repMin [] = []
repMin xs@(x:_) = let (v,m) = runState (f m xs) x in  v

f :: Int -> [Int] -> State Int [Int]
f m xs = mapM (λx -> checkMin x >> return m) xs
 where
    checkMin :: Int -> State Int ()
    checkMin x = modify (min x)
```

Notice there's a lazyness leak here wrt our huge thunk of `min a (min b ( min c ...)))`, but you get the picture.